# Material-UI | Using `theme` in makeStyles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to take an `muiTheme`, pass it down to a component via `ThemeProvider` *and* to its children, and then use the theme's properties in both of them in a classes object that's created by `makeStyles`.

Specifically, these are the components/files I have:

- component `LeftSection` | renders `Subsection` (described below)
- muiTheme `LefSectionTheme` | is used in classes objects in `LeftSection`
- component `RightSection` | renders `Subsection`
- muiTheme `RightSectionTheme`
- component `Subsection`

What I want to do is do add a classes object created by `makeStyles()` in each of the components, and each of them use the theme's properties. I'm not posting code here because I tried a lot of combinations of the functions and I suppose that I just have a hole in my understanding of how some of those functions work.

So here's a reproduction without any classes: [LeftSection and RightSection rendering Subsection with their themes](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-darkness-4uzz3) - to this I want to add classes.

Here is the code of the `Subsection` component where I want to use classes:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/styles";

function Subsection(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <p
      style={{
        color: theme.palette.primary.main
      }}
    >
      test
    </p>
  );
}

export default Subsection;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is the syntax for using classes which use the theme for this styling:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paragraph: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
}));
function Subsection(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <p className={classes.paragraph}>test</p>;
}

export default Subsection;
```

[image: Edit serene-pond-t07i1]

Without seeing the code of what you have tried before, it is hard for me to know what specific holes you may have in your understanding, so if you have specific questions about this I can add some more explanation/references.

Comment: Thanks, it works. :)

I'll try to implement it in my codebase.